# Spring Data Rest and collections with unique constraints

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm evaluating spring-data-rest and am running into a situation where the magic no longer appears to be working in my favor.

Say I have a collection of items.

Parent - 1:M - Child

```
Parent
   Long id
   String foo
   String bar

   @OneToMany(...)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   Collection<Child> items

   setItems(items) {
      this.items.clear();
      this.items.addAll(items);
   }

@Table(name = "items", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"parent_id", "ordinal"})})
Child
   Long id
   String foo
   Integer ordinal
```

The database has a constraint that children of the same parent can't have conflicting values in one particular field, 'ordinal'.

I want to PATCH to the parent entity, overwriting the collection of children. The problem comes with the default behavior of hibernate. Hibernate doesn't flush the changes from when the collection is cleared until after the new items are added. This violates the constraint, even though the eventual state will not.

```
  Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'schema.parent_items' with unique index 'ix_parent_items_id_ordinal'
```

I have tried mapping this constraint to the child entity by using @UniqueConstraints(), but this doesn't appear to change the behavior.

I am currently working around this by manually looking at the current items and updating the ones that would cause the constraint violation with the new values.

Am I missing something? This seems like a fairly common use case, but maybe I'm trying too hard to shoe-horn hibernate into a legacy database design. I'd love to be able to make things work against our current data without having to modify the schema.

I see that I can write a custom controller and service, à la https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks, and this would let me handle the entityManager and flush in between. The problem I see going that way is that it seems that I lose the entire benefit of using spring-data-rest in the first place, which solves 99% of my problems with almost no code. Is there somewhere that I can shim in a custom handler for this operation without rewriting all the other operations I get for free?

Comment: what do you mean by "I lose the entire benefit of using spring-data-rest in the first place"?

Comment: @Kakawait spring-data-rest appears to do a lot of work to seamlessly expose a repository through a rest controller that handles all actions, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, GET, and annotate the entities with links for HATEOAS. Not that it is impossible to write the controller and service layer myself, but I was hoping to be able to interact with spring-data-rest in a way that didn't force me to rewrite all of that because hibernate needs some hand holding.

Comment: Yeah I know SDR but what's the problem to write your own Controller for the 1% of your custom API and let SDR do the rest? For example in my app when I delete an user I just want to update flag active = false. So I just write a UserController with delete method to handle this case then all other case I handle by SDR.

Comment: @Kakawait I must be doing something wrong then. I'll try to get a repo up with a reduction of my issue. I tried to set up only a PATCH controller, but then it didn't seem to fall back to the default SDR controller.

Comment: No you'r not doing "wrong" because you must implement your a specific `HandlerMapping`. I will post an answer because in comment it will be too short

Comment: Why are you not simply replacing the collection of children with the parameter given? I wouldn't manipulate a database loaded collection in the first place.

Comment: @OliverGierke When you say replacing, do you mean something like set(items){this.items = items)} instead of clear/addall?

I tried doing modeling your order-item relationship from restbucks using lombok Setter and orphanRemoval=true, but get the following error when I update the collection:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: domain.parent.items"

I tried following advice like in: http://yeoman-programmer.blogspot.com/2013/05/keep-hibernate-setters-private-for.html, but ended up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to customize *Spring Data REST* (my way to do, I have to speak about with *Spring Data REST* guys) like following:

Consider we have a *exposed repository* `UserRepository` on `/users/`, you should have at least the following API:

```
...
/users/{id} GET
/users/{id} DELETE
...
```

Now you want to override `/users/{id} DELETE` but keep other API to be handle by *Spring Data REST*.

The natural approach (again in my opinion) is to write your own `UserController` (and your custom `UserService`) like following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{user}")
    public void delete(@Valid @PathVariable("user") User user) {
        if (!user.isActive()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(user);
        }
        user.setActive(false);
        userService.save(user);
    }
}
```

But by doing this, the following mapping `/users` will now be handle by `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instead of `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping`.

And if you pay attention on method [handleNoMatch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java#L177) of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping` (parent of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping`) you can see the following thing:

```
else if (patternAndMethodMatches.isEmpty() && !allowedMethods.isEmpty()) {
    throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(request.getMethod(), allowedMethods);
}
```

- `patternAndMethodMatches.isEmpty()`: return `TRUE` if *url* and method (`GET`, `POST`, ...) does not match.

So if you are asking for `/users/{id} GET` it will be `TRUE` because `GET` only exists on *Spring Data REST* exposed repository controller.

- `!allowedMethods.isEmpty()`: return `TRUE` if at least 1 method `GET`, `POST` or something else matches for the given *url*.

And again it's true for `/users/{id} GET` because `/users/{id} DELETE` exists.

So *Spring* will throw an `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`.

---

In order to *by-pass* this problem I created my own `HandlerMapping` with the following logic:

- The `HandlerMapping` has a list of `HandlerMapping` (here `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping` and `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping`)
- The `HandlerMapping` loops over this list and delegate the request. If an exception occurs we keep it (we keep only the first exception in fact) and we continues to the other handler. At the end if all handlers of the list throw an exception we rethrow the first exception (previously keeped).

Moreover we implements `org.springframework.core.Ordered` in order to place the handler before `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Thibaud Lepretre
 */
public class OrderedOverridingHandlerMapping implements HandlerMapping, Ordered {

    private List<HandlerMapping> handlers;

    public OrderedOverridingHandlerMapping(List<HandlerMapping> handlers) {
        Assert.notNull(handlers);
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Exception firstException = null;

        for (HandlerMapping handler : handlers) {
            try {
                return handler.getHandler(request);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (firstException == null) {
                    firstException = e;
                }
            }
        }

        if (firstException != null) {
            throw firstException;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now let's create our bean

```
@Inject
@Bean
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public HandlerMapping orderedOverridingHandlerMapping(HandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping,
                                                      HandlerMapping repositoryExporterHandlerMapping) {
    List<HandlerMapping> handlers = Arrays.asList(requestMappingHandlerMapping, repositoryExporterHandlerMapping);
    return new OrderedOverridingHandlerMapping(handlers);
}
```

*Et voilà*.

Comment: Thank you. I won't have a chance to try this out for a few days, but this looks exactly like what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might consider @Oliver Gierke comment is Spring Data Project Lead developer :)